# dependency problems prevent configuration of kicad-dbg V5 in linux LMDE

Tags: lmde

I have downloaded the KiCad V5 from [here](https://launchpad.net/~js-reynaud/+archive/ubuntu/kicad-5.1/+sourcepub/10392098/+listing-archive-extra) in my  Linux OS (LMDE 3 "Cindy" - Cinnamon (64-bit)) like this :

```
$  uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u4 (2019-07-19)
```

but when I want to install it by this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i kicad.deb
```

i get this error:

```
sudo dpkg -i kicad.deb
(Reading database ... 504372 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack kicad.deb ...
Unpacking kicad-dbg (5.1.4-201908052210+e60b266~84~ubuntu19.10.1) over (5.1.4-201908052210+e60b266~84~ubuntu19.10.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kicad-dbg:
 kicad-dbg depends on kicad (= 5.1.4-201908052210+e60b266~84~ubuntu19.10.1); however:
  Package kicad is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package kicad-dbg (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kicad-dbg
```

I also tried :

```
sudo aptitude install kicad
```

and get this :

```
sudo aptitude install kicad
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kicad libpng12-0{a} libwxbase3.0-0{a} libwxgtk3.0-0{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libboost-context1.62.0{u} libboost-locale1.62.0{u} mint-backgrounds-tessa{u} 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  kicad-dbg{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 3 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.8 MB of archives. After unpacking 16.2 MB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwxgtk3.0-0v5 : Breaks: libwxgtk3.0-0 but 3.0.2-1+b1 is to be installed
 kicad-dbg : Depends: kicad (= 5.1.4-201908052210+e60b266~84~ubuntu19.10.1) but 0.20140622+bzr4027-3 is to be installed
 libwxbase3.0-0v5 : Breaks: libwxbase3.0-0 but 3.0.2-1+b1 is to be installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:                                 
1)     audacity [1:2.1.3-dmo1+deb9u1 (now, oldstable)]              
2)     kicad-dbg [5.1.4-201908052210+e60b266~84~ubuntu19.10.1 (now)]
3)     libwxbase3.0-0v5 [3.0.2+dfsg-4 (now)]                        
4)     libwxgtk3.0-0v5 [3.0.2+dfsg-4 (now)]                         
5)     pgadmin3 [1.22.2-1 (now)]                                    
6)     playonlinux [4.3.4 (now)]                                    
7)     python-wxgtk3.0 [3.0.2.0+dfsg-4 (now)]                       



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] ^X^Z
[8]+  Stopped                 sudo aptitude install kicad
```

so I don't know to remove what package and why?

Thanks for your attention and time.